# User Parameter Restrictions in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, parameters, parameter-passing

Fairly new to SSRS so apologies if this is an easy fix.

I am looking for a solution that will allow me to set which choice(s) from a parameter in an SSRS report a user can select.

As an example I have a single parameter which supplies a drop down list of office locations. Is there a way to restrict which users can select which offices from the list.

Ideally I would like to keep one report rather than creating multiple reports.

Any suggestions or pointers would be gratefully received.

Thanks,

Comment: whats the source of the parameters' values, cube or sql query?

Comment: Hi - it's a sql query (stored procedure) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a parameter to the stored procedure, the dataset will allow you to specify how you want to populate the parameter. You can use the built in SSRS default parameter User!UserID to get the user name of the person logged in.

You can then use the parameter in the stored procedure to filter the choices returned in the drop down menu.

Comment: Thanks - this was exactly what I needed. Spent a while trawling the internet but clearly hadn't got the terms i was looking for.